# makefile error when using string.h

Tags: c, cs50

I realize this has probably been answered but I just cannot find it.  When using "make" to compile the following file:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    // get line of text
string s = GetString();

// print string, one character per line
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
{
    char c = s[i];
    printf("%c\n", c);
}
return 0;
}
```

I get the following message:

```
$ make example
cc     example.c   -o example
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GetString", referenced from:
      _main in example-iPNXBe.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [example] Error 1
```

Comment: And where did you define `GetString()`?

Comment: Why do you think `string.h` includes a struct called `string`?

Comment: @AlexReynolds the header <cs50.h> has a `typedef char *string`.

Comment: Where are `string` and `GetString()` defined?

Comment: Side note: make sure your compiler knows you're using C99 extensions (give gcc the `-std=c99` argument), otherwise `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)` won't compile. Declaration in a `for ()` is not C89 compliant.

Comment: @Asblarf, seems he is using clang, this is C99 per default, I think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - cs50.h GetString error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052468/c-cs50-h-getstring-error)

Answer (score 6):

Judging from [the cs50 page](https://manual.cs50.net/library/#_c) you probably need something like `-lcs50` at the end of the `cc` command.

---

Or you can just use the `cs50.o` object file and link with it.

```
cc example.c cs50.o -o example
```